# Python Multi-threading with PySerial object

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

I am new to Python and programming in general. I am trying to write a device driver using pyserial. I opened a thread that would read data from the device and send it to std out. On my main loop I used a function that would read instructions from std in as strings and write them to the device using a dictionary.

My program is reading my instructions but is not displaying any data that should be coming out of the device - I know its writing to the device because it crashes when I use an instruction not in my dictionary. Here is how my code is structured:

```
import serial
import threading
#ser is my serial object

def writeInstruction(ser):
#reads an instruction string from stdin and writes the corresponding instruction to the device
    instruction = raw_input('cmd> ')
    if instr == 'disable_all': defaultMode(ser)
    else: ser.write(dictionaryOfInstructions[instruction])
    time.sleep(.5)

def readData(ser):
# - Reads one package from the device, calculates the checksum and outputs through stdout
# - the package content (excludes the Package head, length, and checksum) as a string
    while True:
          packetHead = binascii.hexlify(ser.read(2))
          packetLength = binascii.hexlify(ser.read(1))
          packetContent = binascii.hexlify(ser.read(int(packetLength, 16) - 1))

          if checkSum(packetHead + packetLength + packetContent):
             print packetContent

readThread = threading.Thread (target = readData, args = ser)
readThread.start()

while True:
      writeInstr(ser)
```

What is the proper way to handle serial objects in multi-threaded programming?

Comment: It would help to know what you are attempting to do in `readData(ser)`. I'm wondering if your thread is done before you get any data. and also `writeInstruction(ser)` can your provide more code from those functions?

Comment: writeInstruction(ser) turns on the device's data collection (medical device) readData(ser) reads individual packets from the device and checksums them

Comment: The posted code is not sufficient to diagnose the problem. Try to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Comment: What is the variable `pm` in `writeInstruction()`? Should that not be `ser`?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with that code. It may be a protocol issue, depending on what the device actually is.