# Removing indexes before Update on a live Database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku-postgres

We are working on a live Postgres Database on Heroku. We need to update around 5 million rows using regex replacing multiple strings, which will mean performing potentially around 100 million updates total.

We are updating it this way: (using psycopg2)

```
for element in list:
    cursor.execute("Update table set text = regexp_replace(text, %s, 'NewWord', 'gi') where date >= '2017-12-31';", [element])
```

The database is live and linked to our Django website, and we need to roll a new feature within 3 days requiring this update to the database. Postgres Guides say that it's much faster if we remove indexes, but removing foreign key indexes might stop some of our django functionality and take the website down. Even so, we are able to take the side down for one to two days during the weekend, but nothing more.

So :

1. Is it safe to assume that by removing the Indexes, 100 million
   updates could be done in a day?
2. if so, Should we also remove Primary
   Key Indexes?
3. If not, how much time would we assume a similar
   update will take without removing the Indexes?

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to rely on Django ORM (or SQLAlchemy if used) to just update the records using your models? It's generally discouraged to alter schema outside Django (Django shell or Django Admin) as brings potential inconsistency into data.

Comment: This sounds more like a Heroku question than a postgres question, since so much of the answer depends on hardware and configuration. Given that, have you tried, say, issuing 10k updates as a benchmark?

Comment: Also, updating each row 20x is going to bloat your table something awful (postgres makes a copy of a row for every update, and those copies only get cleaned up by vacuuming). Among other things, that means the updates will likely take longer as you go on. If you can reduce them to a single update per row, that will definitely help you.

Comment: @jmelesky Does that mean that it would be more efficient to do the string replacment in python and then do one update per row ? I thought that python would be slower than allowing Postgres to do mos tof the stuff

Comment: @dmitryro : We didn't want to use the ORM outside of Django, and this is just a pythoon script running. It's true that the ORM is safer but in the interest of time we decided to go for the quick and dirty solution, since we're closely monitoring what it's doing. But does the Django ORM bring a performance increase ? If so, we could do that

Comment: It's probably easier to use python's threading module like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153897/python-multi-threading-with-pyserial-object/38154084#38154084     - or using message queue, but generally giving Django control (view -> callback -> model query will guarantee you have your data consistent and probably faster than just running the psycopg2 on its own. You can run a snapshot query to see how it runs and if happy run it all.

Comment: @NebrasJemel, honestly I don't know enough about your problem to say. What I can say is: 1- if you have a sense of the size of the problem, and a time span available, you can benchmark based on a smaller version and extrapolate, and 2- 20 updates is going to take longer than 1 update, and make the table slower, too, until you issue a `vacuum full` or the autovacuum catches up. Really, though, I encourage you to benchmark -- it's entirely possible this is an hour-long run rather than a three day run, and you'll only figure it out by testing.

Comment: Would it be faster than running psycopg if we remove the indexes ? We have to get this done by Sunday , and having a for loop in python just for string replacement seems like a bigger waste of time...

Comment: Since I have no idea, and nobody can know, because your database is unknown, and your performance on Heroku (particularly i/o) is unknown. You really need to measure it yourself.

Comment: As long as you do it asynchronously and allocate enough with threading that should not be a big deal - string processing is slow by nature but when your pool is sufficient - it's probably ok.

Comment: Thank You. I think I over estimated the size of the problem , this should be done in time

Comment: The largest win is to prevent meaningless updates by adding a '<>' condition to the where clause like `UPDATE t SET c = some_expression WHERE original_condition AND c <> some_expression;` This will avoid useless row versions to be created. [and I think that if the column needs updates like this, an index in this column will make no sense at all]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 100 million updates can be done within an hour. (if the row size is not too large)
2. No. The primary key is not affected by updating the text field, so you should leave it alone
3. The time needed for an update is approximately the same with or without an index **(if there is no index on the affected text field)**

your query (for simplicity, I removed the parametrisation, and replaced {table,date,text} by {ztable,zdate,ztext}, because it are keywords):

```
Update ztable
set ztext = regexp_replace(ztext, 'Oldword', 'NewWord', 'gi')
where zdate >= '2017-12-31';
```

Can be speeded up a lot by adding an extra condition to the where clause, like in:

```
Update ztable
set ztext = regexp_replace(ztext, 'Oldword', 'NewWord', 'gi')
where zdate >= '2017-12-31'
AND ztext LIKE '%Oldword%'
;
```

This will avoid extra row-versions to be created if the update actually does nothing to a row. (an update costs 1 read-I/O + approx 3 I/Os if the row is actually changed, the number of affected disk blocks depends on the sparsety and the row size)

Extra note: if there is an index on the `ztext` column: throw it away; it is probably useless. 
Maybe extra performance can be gained by removing the loop in the front-end, and putting all logic in the UPDATE.