# Multiprocessing in python running in sequence

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a job that requires lots of database inserts and extracts.  I would like to use multiprocessing to speed up the work.

The process being called does have some variable statements which I'm expecting to be printed, these indicate the jobs are running in sequence 
rather than simultaneously.

```
import rd_functions as rd
import multiprocessing
import sys

start_pos = int(sys.argv[1])
end_pos = int(sys.argv[2])
cores = int(sys.argv[3])

if end_pos == start_pos:
    single_core = 0

else:
    single_core = (end_pos - start_pos) / cores

core1_start = start_pos
core1_end = start_pos + single_core

jobs = []

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=rd.backdate_worker(core1_start,core1_end))
jobs.append(p)

if cores >= 2:
    core2_start = core1_start + single_core + 1
    core2_end = core2_start + single_core
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=rd.backdate_worker(core2_start, core2_end))
    jobs.append(p)

...    

if cores >= 8:
    core8_start = core7_start + single_core + 1
    core8_end = core8_start + single_core
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=rd.backdate_worker(core8_start, core8_end))
    jobs.append(p)

p.start
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153897/python-multi-threading-with-pyserial-object/38154084#38154084

Comment: I'm not really sure what I reading :/ I don't understand how I would call my function multiple times.

Comment: You don't need to call it multiple times. Once decorated, the Thread class will take care of allocating thread for the function call.

Comment: My CPU usage is taken up on SQL loads rather than python processes, I want to split the load on the SQL loads. Each process would need a pre-defined range to work on

Comment: So by placing your SQL calls into functions decorated like @run_async you will dramatically decrease the load. Alternatively, you can use message queue like python rq (redis queue) to place your calls as tasks in the queue.